# Magento 1.9 fatal error Mage_Configurableswatches_Helper_Productimg' not found

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, fatal-error, configurable-swatches, placeholder

i faced with a `Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Configurableswatches_Helper_Productimg' not found in /app/Mage.php on line 547` while **flushing the swatch image cache**.

Please let me know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Did you add any module? or create any module for Productimg?

Comment: Pls check Productimg.php available at location - app/code/core/Mage/ConfigurableSwatches/Helper/

Comment: no not created any modules related to products Images but the 1 more issue occure with products images. whenever a upload the image while adding the products from admin extra placeholder image also uploaded for that products.

Comment: @Abdul file is there but I did not change a single word in that file.

Comment: have you installed any patch?

Comment: No, not install any patch

Comment: have you used anywhere Configurableswatches helper ?

Comment: In your error module namespace is change Mage_Configurableswatches

Comment: Default name space is : Mage_ConfigurableSwatches

Comment: No I did not used Configurableswatches helper